# Fixing IE8 issue with site made with Headway Theme

Tags: wordpress, internet-explorer-8, ie8-compatibility-mode

I created a site using the Headway theme (version 3.5.5) for `WordPress`. It works fine in every browser except `IE8`. I get a single smiley face where the website is supposed to be.

I tried the standard `IE 8` compatability mode fix but it didn't make any difference (other than making the site render less faithfully in later versions of IE).

The url is [www.stonefashion.com](http://www.stonefashion.com). I don't have the reputation points to post an image but you can see how this looks at http://netrenderer.com/index.php

Comment: Is the only way you've checked it IE8 though netrender, because it looks fine in an actual copy of IE8. Ok, it doesn't look fine, but it shows the elements of the page.  The styling is messed up on the menu, but it's there, same with the rest of the page.

Answer (score 0):

I absolutely hate IE, specially versions 6, 7 and 8. When you are designing a wordpress theme, you have to style it twice, once for proper browsers and then for the IE ancients. The other big thing to remember, these ancients don't have support for media queries.

So to solve your problem, create a stylesheet called `ie.css`. You will use this to do all your styling for IE 7 and 8.

Next you will need to enqueue that stylesheet, but we will enqueue it conditionally. This stylesheet will only load for IE versions up to IE8. So in your functions.php, add the following

```
function enqueque_ie_stylesheet() {
// Load the Internet Explorer specific.  stylesheet.
 wp_enqueue_style( 'style-ie',   get_template_directory_uri() . '/ie.css',   array(), '' );
    wp_style_add_data( 'style-ie', 'conditional', 'lt IE 9' );
 }
add_action( 'wp_enqueue_scripts', 'enqueue_ie_stylesheet' );
```

You can now add your styles in `ie.css`. Just remember to change `get_template_directory_uri` to `get_stylesheet_directory_uri` if you are using a child theme